# SQL logging in EntityFramework < 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there any interceptor which logs sql query available with EF version < 6.0.
How to log the sql query executed and elapsed time by using the configuration file without any code intervention? This [article](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/09/ef-6-1-turning-on-logging-without-recompiling/#comment-13653) explains the interceptor introduced  with EF6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this before EF6, this is why the feature was introduced.

If you've got a full or Developer Edition of SQL server installed, you can use the SQL Profiler tool to view commands being executed on the database, which will also contain the performance metrics.